# How does Newton's third law apply to magnetism?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, angular-momentum, conservation-laws, electromagnetic-induction

As a magnet passes through a solenoid, currents are induced in the wire with an angular momentum. Since the induced magnetic solenoid repels the magnet linearly, it cannot allow for the conservation of angular momentum. There is another centripetal force that appears to push the electrons in the magnet as it passes through the magnetic solenoid. But again, this cannot account for the conservation of angular momentum?

How can I understand how momentum and energy are conserved in any electromagnetic interaction? Without going into too much mathematical detail, but enough to gain a heuristic understanding?

Comment: What about the "current" of the positive atoms. They'd "flow" in the opposite direction canceling $L$

Comment: So you are saying that the ions in the wire are pushed back equally, causing the solenoid to turn ever so slightly? It makes sense but i want to be able to understand this without resorting to specific guesses depending on the setup

Comment: Just imagine your wire is made out of positronium (or let's say some electron positron plasma not annihilating), what would happen if both are free to move.

Comment: Also note that despite the two up-votes of the answer below, I do not agree for several reasons. One being that the angular momentum in the field does not apriori know in which sense the coil turns.

Comment: Not practical...maybe... a good question though.

Comment: Well, I know that with other forces, momentum is always conserved because the force equation is symmetrical for both particles. This is also true for magnetism. I'll avoid generalisations like the biot savart equation but a simple equation for magnitude of magnetic force between two currents is $\frac{\mu I_1I_2}{2\pi r}$. This is symmetrical in magnitude. And if we consider the properties of the cross product, the directions are flipped. So my guess is that there *is* a force on the magnet causing it to turn slightly, and the force is on the electrons in the magnet?

Comment: I think a simplification of your original problem is a moving charge passing a permanent magnet. It will start spinning around the field lines leading to your original question. I am not sure about your current example, but I agree that as the magnet is forcing the charge to change the linear motion, there must be the equal and opposite force of the charge on the magnet.

Comment: Also not that a spinning/ accelerated charge radiates, which is actually a mechanism for loosing energy and angular momentum.

Comment: I actually see a mechanism that makes the magnet spin, but it would be indirect. The current produces an inhomogeneous field opposite to the magnet. This would make the magnetization of the permanent magnet precess. The precession would the damp into the solid. I am also not convinced yet that this is enough to compensate for the current.

Comment: Moreover, note that in a conducting magnet, the field of the coil would induce an opposite turning current on the magnets surface. All in all, plenty of mechanisms where angular momentum is involved.

Comment: ok, I feel that I have a number of misconceptions and gaps in understanding that may only be resolved through further study, I appreciate your effort to explain this though

Comment: I think it is a really good fundamental question. What I can say quite sure is that without the wire the electrons would not necessarily spin around the magnet (see the comment on a charge passing the magnet). It is therefore clear that you need the confinement by the wire and, hence, an interaction with the wire. This includes an acceleration of the coil as the induced field is repelled by the magnet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the long discussion, let me summarize my conclusions so far.
I assume that the coil axis and the magnet movement are in $z$-direction.
I am quite sure that it is not the electromagnetic field of the magnet. $E$ is very likely to be of type $(E_r,E_\theta, E_\phi)=(0,E_\theta(r,\phi),0)$ meaning that $S$ is of type $(S_r(r,\phi),0,S_\phi(r,\phi))$ (see image) meaning that $\cal L$ is of type $(0,{\cal{L}}_{\theta}(r,\phi),0)$,i.e. the integral around $\theta$ of the angular momentum is zero and locally it is not pointing in $z$ while the angular momentum of the current is. 
[image: Poynting field]

**Fig. 1 Poynting filed of moving circular current**

Furthermore, I am sure that a free electron would not rotate around the magnet but would make some local turning.[image: Trajectories]

**Fig. 2 Trajectories of charged particles in the field of a circular current**

Hence, to get the circular motion there is obviously a strong interaction of the current with the confinement, i.e. the wire. I have to think about the details, but would expect the coil to turn in the opposite direction.

Finally, it is very important that magnetization itself is angular momentum. In the permanent magnet it is most likely to come from the electron spins, but in a simplified way it may be imagined as a circular current as well. In this simple image the circulating current in the coil is producing an opposite field in the permanent magnet, reducing its magnetization, or in the simplified image, its current and, therefore, its angular momentum. In terms of magnetization and spin, what is happening is the following. The magnetization starts to precess around the local field, so the total magnetization in $z$-direction reduces, due to cylindrical symmetry all new in-plane components sum up to zero.

From this point of view the magnet is already bringing plenty of angular momentum and borrowing some of it to the current.

Similar thinking might help understanding how the free charge gets angular momentum when passing a magnetic field, starting to "circulate" as in Fig. 2.

The list of effects and the corresponding understanding might not be complete, but it gives an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Without going into too much mathematical detail, the best answer is that the **electromagnetic field itself carries angular momentum**. The density of the angular momentum of an electromagnetic field can be derived from the Poynting vector

$$\textbf{S}=\frac{1}{\mu_0}\left(\textbf{E}\times\textbf{B}\right)$$

From which the momentum density is given by $\boldsymbol{\mathcal{P}}=\epsilon_0\mu_0\textbf{S}$, and so the electromagnetic angular momentum density is given by

$$\boldsymbol{\mathcal{L}}=\textbf{r}\times\boldsymbol{\mathcal{P}}=\epsilon_0\,\textbf{r}\times\left(\textbf{E}\times\textbf{B}\right)=\epsilon_0\left((\textbf{r}\cdot\textbf{B})\,\textbf{E}-\left(\textbf{E}\cdot\textbf{B}\right)\,\textbf{r}\right)$$

The total angular momentum derived from this density is exactly what cancels the angular momentum of the current in the solenoid.

Energy is not conserved in the interaction since energy is being put in my whatever force is pushing the magnet.

I hope this helped clear up some confusion!

Comment: So as the moving permanent magnet is the source of the EM-field, it eventually must spin?

Comment: The magnet doesn't have to spin. If I kept it moving only in a straight line with no spinning the current would still be induced. The angular momentum comes from the angular momentum contained **within** the electromagnetic field. It is a little weird to think that a field (something you can't see or touch) can contain angular momentum, but this is the case.

Comment: I don't have a problem with an em-field having angular momentum, but here the current is induced due to the linear motion of permanent magnet (and for simplicity I assume that this coincides with the solenoid axis) Hence, the acceleration of the permanent must introduce the angular momentum. So is it present even without the solenoid? That would imply that the accelerating magnet should start spinning. And would that be cw or ccw?